# how to move individual words in css

Tags: css

I've got a mock-up [(img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMwJ7.jpg) that I'm attempting to replicate and I'm having a hard time getting everything in just the right place [(img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saZEa.jpg).

If I didn't have the gradient over the top this would be easy -- I would just use two separate h1 elements and move them around as needed. The problem is if I do that, the gradient doesn't persist over both elements [(img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjCcZ.jpg).

I can do other styling changes to the second word (like making it smaller or changing its colour) by wrapping it inside of another tag but I just want to move it slightly up and slightly to the left and that doesn't seem to work.

Here is some working code, does anyone have any thoughts?

```css
#foo {
  font-family: 'Fugaz One', 'arial black', sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 transform: rotate(-7.7deg);
 color: transparent;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 background-clip: text;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(7.7deg, #ef8181, #fa9551); 
 background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(7.7deg, #ef8181, #fa9551); 
 background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(7.7deg, #ef8181, #fa9551); 
 background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(7.7deg, #ef8181, #fa9551); 
 background-image:         linear-gradient(7.7deg, #ef8181, #fa9551); 
 font-size: 16vw;
 left: -2vw;
 top: -10vh;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="foo">TEXT<br>THERE</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#foo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Fugaz One', 'arial black', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(-7.7deg);
  line-height: 0.9;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(7.7deg, #ef8181, #fa9551);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(7.7deg, #ef8181, #fa9551);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(7.7deg, #ef8181, #fa9551);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(7.7deg, #ef8181, #fa9551);
  background-image: linear-gradient(7.7deg, #ef8181, #fa9551);
  font-size: 16vw;
}

span {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

span:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: 35px;

}
```

```html
<h1 id="foo"><span>TEXT</span><span>THERE<span></h1>
```

I would recommend adding `line-height` and `text-indent` to `#foo`. I added

`#foo {
   line-height: 13vw;
   text-indent: 11px;
}`

`line-height` will help reduce the spacing between each work, and `text-indent` helps offset the text since it has been rotated.  I hope this helps :).

As a side note an SVG would be a great option to use here instead of CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't used SVG before, is there any chance you could show a quick example of how you could move each line individually while having the same gradient persistent across both?

Comment: In order to move each word individually, you should wrap each word in a `span` tag.  `span` tags by default display inline so it won't impact the gradient. Lastly, you can use `margin-left` to move the `span` individually. `text-indent` won't work on span tags because they're inline elements.


`<h1 id="foo"><span>TEXT</span><br><span>THERE<span></h1>`

Comment: ah great! I had tried using span to select the second word individually, but didn't think of using margin-left. That's perfect, moves it left and right exactly how I wanted it to.

Do you know what I would do to move up and down? I've tried using transform:translate() and margin-top and they don't seem to work?

Comment: Margin top/bottom doesn't work for inline elements. Another route you could take is to remove the `<br>`and control the line breaking manually. This can be done by applying `display: flex`, `flex-direction: column`, and `line-height: 14vw` to `#foo`. Now the span tags are flex children and margin top/bottom will work.

Comment: sorry, I haven't worked with flex before, can you give an example of what you mean? My html looks like this and I think that because the span elements are within the h1, it thinks that there's only one element in the flex box?

<div id="container">
 <h1 id="foo"><span id="firstspan">TEXT</span>
 <span id="secondspan">HERE</span></h1>
</div>

Comment: I've updated my answer for you to see a working example.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the vertical spacing between the two words with the `line-height` property. You can move the second word to the left by using the `text-indent` property to move the first line/word to the right and then offsetting the `left` property.

```css
#foo {
  font-family: 'Fugaz One', 'arial black', sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 color: transparent;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 background-clip: text;
        transform:skew(-10deg) rotate(-7.7deg);
        line-height: 0.9;
        text-indent:-10px;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(7.7deg, #ef8181, #fa9551); 
 background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(7.7deg, #ef8181, #fa9551); 
 background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(7.7deg, #ef8181, #fa9551); 
 background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(7.7deg, #ef8181, #fa9551); 
 background-image:         linear-gradient(7.7deg, #ef8181, #fa9551); 
 font-size: 16vw;
 left: 0vw;
 top: -10vh;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="foo">TEXT<br>THERE</h1>
```

P.S. I also added a little bit Skew to the `transform` property. I think in general an easier approach would be to keep each word in a separate h1 element and create two separate linear gradients, one applied to the first word and the other to the second.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the response. I had used line-height before, but the problem is that it chops off the top of some of my letters (S, B and C specifically) when the distance between the two words was too close.

Good work around using text-indent, but I'm wondering if there's another way to do it that is a bit more general? Say if there was a paragraph of text and you just wanted to move one of the words in the middle slightly offset from the rest?

Comment: hmm the skew doesn't seem to help the top of the letters from being chopped for me. And also by skewing the text it makes it less like the mock-up objective.

I thought about having separate h1 with separate gradient colours (selected from the mock-up), but I've got got lots of lines that this applies to and there's got to be a more efficient way than copying and pasting all of those colour codes.