# why doesn't my flexbox display in safari?

Tags: css, safari

I have some text in a slightly unusual flexbox/span arrangement [(the reason for which is explained here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53662915/how-to-move-individual-words-in-css) and it's not displaying in Safari. It appears fine in all other browsers I've tried.

It seems this is common question, but [most of the suggestions are to include different display:flex options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899943/how-do-i-make-flex-box-work-in-safari), which I have applied but it still doesn't work.

Does anybody have any ideas?

HTML

```
<h1>
   <span id="firstspan">this</span>
   <span id="secondspan">phrase</span>
</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
   font-family: 'Fugaz One', serif;
   font-weight:300;
   position: absolute;
   transform: rotate(-7.7deg);
   color: transparent;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   background-clip: text;
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(8deg, #d58da3, #fa8567, #fa9551); 
   background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(8deg, #d58da3, #fa8567, #fa9551); 
   background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(8deg, #d58da3, #fa8567, #fa9551); 
   background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(8deg, #d58da3, #fa8567, #fa9551);  
   background-image:         linear-gradient(8deg, #d58da3, #fa8567, #fa9551); 
   background-position-y: 1vw;
   display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
   display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
   display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
   display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: column;
   flex-direction: column;
   font-size: 17.3vw;
   left: -2vw;
   top: calc(270px - 20vw); /*a smaller vw and it will move up as you shrink, a smaller px and it will shift up*/
}

#secondspan {
   font-size: 13.7vw;
   margin-left: -1vw;
   margin-top: -10.5vw;
}
```

Comment: There is a bug in the official safari bug tracker. Unfortunately it looks like nobody has looked into it for the last two years:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=169125

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289537/webkit-text-fill-color-transparent-not-working-in-safari-7-1-7

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```css
h1 {
   font-family: 'Fugaz One', serif;
   font-weight:300;
   position: absolute;
   transform: rotate(-7.7deg);
   color: transparent;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   background-clip: text;
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(8deg, #d58da3, #fa8567, #fa9551); 
   background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(8deg, #d58da3, #fa8567, #fa9551); 
   background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(8deg, #d58da3, #fa8567, #fa9551); 
   background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(8deg, #d58da3, #fa8567, #fa9551);  
   background-image:         linear-gradient(8deg, #d58da3, #fa8567, #fa9551); 
   background-position-y: 1vw;
   display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
   display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
   display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
   display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: column;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   align-items: flex-start;
   
   font-size: 17.3vw;
   left: -2vw;
   top: calc(270px - 20vw); /*a smaller vw and it will move up as you shrink, a smaller px and it will shift up*/
}

#secondspan {
   font-size: 13.7vw;
   margin-left: -1vw;
   margin-top: -10.5vw;
}
```

```html
<h1>
   <span id="firstspan">this</span>
   <span id="secondspan">phrase</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: hmm well the bad news is that I'm still not able to see it on Safari, but the good news is that when I select the area where it should be I can select the text. Which must mean that it's "color: transparent;" is working but for some reason the gradient isn't. Do you have any idea why?